# Where should I look for collaborators / mentees?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am a researcher working in academia in [bioinformatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioinformatics) and [computational biology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_biology). 
I have several ideas for small pet projects (open source, of course) where I could be a mentor to a less experienced developer. I would happily collaborate with people all around the world and teach them, just for fun. These are not at all job positions, nor internships. No money involved either. Where should I advertise my offers? Is there a well-known community for mentoring in research? Is it on any of the Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Not really, now I only know that I *should not* ask on any StackExchange sites. But I still don't know where *should* I. Is there a platform to match people for mentoring?

Comment: this is not the place to learn about what else is there outside in the internet, sorry. This site is for questions about Stack Exchange network, see [help/on-topic]

Comment: Yes, I think so, thanks! People there say to ask at academia.stackexchange.com, but this is a StackExchange site... I think I will try nonetheless...

Comment: you may have better luck asking in [meta-tag:chat] over there. Chat doesn't have such strict scope limitations as main / meta sites

Answer (score 7):

Stack Exchange is not the place for any of these kinds of requests.  You may want to try universities or institutions of higher education instead, as they probably have a workflow for requests like this already.